# Semaphore-implemented Producer-Consumer oriented thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, semaphore, producer-consumer

I am currently working on an educational assignment in which i have to implement a Semaphore only thread-safe thread pool.

I mustn't use during my assignment: `Synchronize` `wait` `notify` `sleep` or any thread-safe API's.

firstly without getting too much into the code i have:

- Implemented a Thread-safe queue (no two threads can queue\dequeue at the same time) (i have tested this problem with `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and the problem persists)

The design itself:

Shared:

- `Tasks` semaphore = 0
- `Available` semaphore = 0
- `Tasks_Queue` queue
- `Available_Queue` queue

Worker Threads:

- `Blocked` semaphore = 0

General Info:

- Only manager(single thread) can dequeue `Tasks_Queue` and `Available_Queue`
- Only App-Main(single thread) can enqueue tasks is `Tasks_Queue`
- Each worker thread can enqueue themselves in `Available_Queue`

So we have a mix of a single producer, a single manager and several consumers.

- When the app first starts each of the worker threads gets started and immediately enqueues itself in `Available_Queue`, releases `Available` semaphore and gets blocked acquiring it's personal `Blocked` semaphore.
- Whenever App-Main queues a new task it releases `Task` Semaphore
- Whenever Manager wishes to execute a new task it must first acquire both `Tasks` and `Available` semaphores.

My question:

during the app's runtime the function `dequeue_worker()` returns a null worker, even though a semaphore is placed to protect access to the queue when it is known that there are no available worker threads.

i have "solved" the problem by recursively calling `dequeue_worker()` if it draws a null thread, BUT doing so is suppose to make an acquisition of a semaphore permit lost forever. yet when i limit the amount of workers to 1 the worker does not get blocked forever.

1) what's the break-point of my original design?

2) why doesn't my "solution" break the design even further?!

Code snippets:

```
// only gets called by Worker threads: enqueue_worker(this);
    private void enqueue_worker(Worker worker) {
       available_queue.add(worker);
       available.release();
    }

// only gets called by App-Main (a single thread)
    public void enqueue_task(Query query) {
        tasks_queue.add(query);
        tasks.release();
    }

// only gets called by Manager(a single Thread) 
    private Worker dequeue_worker() {
        Worker worker = null;
        try {
            available.acquire();
            worker = available_queue.poll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // shouldn't happen
        } // **** the solution: ****
        if (worker==null) worker = dequeue_worker(); // TODO: find out why
        return worker;
    }

// only gets called by Manager(a single Thread) 
    private Query dequeue_task() {
        Query query = null;
        try {
            tasks.acquire();
            query = tasks_queue.poll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // shouldn't happen
        } 
        return query;
    }

// gets called by Manager (a single thread)
    private void execute() { // check if task is available and executes it
        Worker worker = dequeue_worker(); // available.down()
        Query query = dequeue_task(); //task.down()
        worker.setData(query);
        worker.blocked.release();
    }
```

And finally Worker's `Run()` method:

```
while (true) { // main infinite loop

                enqueue_worker(this);
                acquire(); // blocked.acquire();
                <C.S>
                available.release();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `available.release()` twice, once in `enqueue_worker`, second time in a main loop.

Comment: its Thread-Safe not blocking. my blocking mechanism is implemented via `Available` and `Tasks` semaphores

Comment: your recursive iteration does the same, but very inefficiently

Comment: i want to understand how did the availlable.acquire() call even allowed a .poll() of a null object.

Comment: you are calling `available.release()` twice, once in `enqueue_worker`, second time in main loop

Comment: how on earth did i miss that?! thank you so much! please edit your answer to reflect this catch and i'll pick is as preferred answer.